# Translation of $[\forall xP(x) \rightarrow (\forall x) Q(x)] \rightarrow (\forall x) [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]$ to English

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am having trouble translating the following statement to English.

$$[(\forall x)P(x) \rightarrow (\forall x)Q(x)] \rightarrow (\forall x)[P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]$$

I am being asked to perform some validity/interpretation, but am having trouble wrapping my head around what exactly it is saying.

Without the quantifiers, its easy enough: ($P$ implies $Q$) implies ($P$ implies $Q$).

With quantifiers, (For $x$, if every $P$ implies every $Q$) then (For all, $P$ implies $Q$)? Or something like that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the evening where I am.

Comment: Good evening to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be:
($P$ is true for all $x$ implies $Q$ is true for all $x$) implies (for all $x$, $P$ is true implies $Q$ is true)
Compact version:
($P$ for all $x$ implies $Q$ for all $x$) implies (for all $x$, $P$ implies $Q$)

Answer (score 2):

Another variation:

If having a property $P$ for every $x$ is a sufficient condition for every $x$ having a property $Q$, then every element $x$ with the property $P$ has the property $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

If, if for all x x is a P, then for all x x is a Q, then for all x, if x is a P, then x is a Q.